# Update a row from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following .csv file which I want to read and possibly modify some of the fields. My csv file looks like:

```
0   id name    value1 value2
1   .. ..      0       0
2   .. ramon   0       0
3   .. ..      0       0
4   .. ..      0       0
5   .. ..      0       0
```

I would like to modify the value2 from the row with name ramon. For this reason, I did the following:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('temp.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
df[(df.name == "ramon")]['value2'] = 10
```

Apparently, I cannot modify the value in this way. How can I properly update the `value2` field for this row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. You are looking for the `.loc` method:

`df.loc[df['name'] == 'ramon',"value2"] = 10`